# React TS - Not able to return the correct component in if statement

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, react-component, react-typescript

I have a function which returns the react content (JSX.Element) in the if statement. But it does not seem to work. I only get the first statement to trigger

I have recreated the problem with codesandbox with a simple example. To test this just keep pressing the button and view the console.log. to see if the rndType has changed. It should show the other heading in that case, but it doesnt

```
export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({ rnd: 100 });
  const [name, setName] = useState({ rnd: "Name" });

  const type = ["Number", "Text"];

  const getContent = () => {
    let rndNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length);
    let rndType = type[rndNo];
    console.log("rndType", rndType);

    if (rndType === "Number") {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>{number.rnd}</h1>
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>{name.rnd}</h1>
        </>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getContent()}

      <button onClick={() => getContent()}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: my-description]

Answer (score 2):

component will only rerender on state update, and you don't update any. you can store the selected type in a state then it would work as expected:

```
export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({ rnd: 100 });
  const [name, setName] = useState({ rnd: "Name" });
  const [type, setType] = useState("Text");

  const types = ["Number", "Text"];

  const getContent = () => {
    const content = type === "Number" ? number.rnd : name.rnd
    return <h1>{content}</h1>
  };

  const setRandomType = () => {
    let rndNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * types.length);
    let rndType = types[rndNo];
    setType(rndType);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getContent()}

      <button onClick={setRandomType}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: also i refactored `getContent` a little bit to keep it cleaner. fwiw you could also return only `content` and at return statement do `<h1>{ getContent() }</h1>`